# splitting strings using re.split()

Tags: python, string, split

I have a many emails in a string. I need to split this string into separate emails. Each email starts with "From:" in a new line. If there were no "From:" anywhere else in the body then the following works -

```
list_of_email_strings = re.split("From:", my_email_text_string)
```

I need to though ignore "From:" that does not occur right after a new line. The following (with caret) does  not work -

```
list_of_email_strings = re.split("^From:", my_email_text_string)
```

Solution ?

Comment: Why not split on newline and discard the `From:` on each item?

Comment: You'd probably want to keep the `From:`, no?

Comment: Is your string of emails a mailbox file of some kind? If so, you might try the [`mailbox` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/mailbox.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `\n` with a non-consuming lookahead assertion `(?=...)` which has the advantage of not eating the string upon which you're splitting (e.g. "From:" stays intact).

```
list_of_email_strings = re.split("\n(?=From:)", my_email_text_string)
```

E.g.:

```
>>> s = "From: ...\nFrom: ...\nFrom: ..."
>>> re.split("\n(?=From:)", s)
['From:...', 'From:...', 'From:...']
```

As compared to:

```
>>> re.split("\nFrom:", s)
['From: ...', ' ...', ' ...']
```

Comment: thanks. works like a  charm. I did figure out the \n part but the lookahead assertion is a nice tip.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to wim's answer, but with From: being added back into the emails as needed:

```
list = ['From:' + msg for msg in ('\n' + text).split('\nFrom:')]
```

However, there are native Python modules which give you finer and more reliable control over reading in email files like the one you describe. [email](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email) and [mailbox](http://docs.python.org/2/library/mailbox.html) come to mind.

Assuming these are standard mbox style emails in which each file starts with a "From:" and then some header lines, possibly a digest, etc. - like those used by sendmail or Postfix - something like this will work if you either first write the string to file or just use an existing file:

```
mbox = mailbox.mbox(path_to_mailbox_file)
mbox.lock()  # only if you're using an active mailbox file
message_strings = [message.as_string() for message in mbox]
mbox.unlock()  # again, only if you're using an acture mailbox file
mbox.close()
```

To get the number of messages, just use `len(mbox)`.

There are a ton of other useful features. I've made a few scripts using these mudules and been very hapy with the results. (Note that [`as_string`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.as_string) may reformat some of the header.)

Comment: I agree with recommending the `mailbox` module, but splitting and reassembling the string like that is kludgy.

Comment: That's pretty fair. I rewrote it to use a more compact list comprehension, but your regex is still more elegant IMHO. I used `timeit` to test the two and they're almost the same efficiency, so I think your regex would be better in most cases, since it's more readable.